# How to verify the ACE-CORBA service local windows machine

Tags: java, tcp, corba, ace-tao

I'm able to create docker container for ACE-TAO service , and able to  access  it  from parent windows machine using port-forwarding  concept.

From  browser i try  to hit  the `localhost:forward-port` and getting `"ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"` and TAO service is running in  docker container.

If I want to  verify in local, whether its connected properly or  not.
How can I write `Java` code to verify?

Comment: What shall your Java code do? Connecting to a port and making a TCP connect test?

Comment: Yes , It'll connect to the port and tell Connection success

Answer (score 0):

The following java code connects to `localhost:17500` and prints out a message saying whether or not it could create a tcp connection.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class TCPClient
{
 public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
 {
   try {
    Socket clientSocket = new Socket("localhost", 17500);
    System.out.println("Could connect");
   }
   catch (ConnectException e) {
    System.out.println("Cannot connect");
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to  verify with provided code successfully.

Comment: Same thing I need to  verify  with ORBEndpoint like following code

Comment: I don't know what you mean